# Compile error: Argument not optional vba excel

Tags: excel, vba, compiler-errors

I'm trying to write a code where I input an image after checking the info in each sheet of my workbook. Since I added for each to the code it stopped working and started giving me this compile error message, the code works without the for each but i want it to be automatic. Can you help?

```
Sub ForEachWs()
Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    Call Worksheet_SelectionChange
    Next ws

End Sub
```

---

```
Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

   On Error Resume Next

    If Target.Column = 2 And Target.Row = 1 Then ' onde clicar para buscar imagem

        BuscarImagemTavares (Target.Value)

    End If

End Sub
```

---

```
Sub BuscarImagemTavares(Produto As String)
    On Error Resume Next
    'Autor: Tavares

    If Range("B2") = "ok" Then 'Verifica se celula B2 tem ok se sim não insere a imagem novamente
    Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim Imagem, CaminhoImagem As String

    If Len(Produto) = 3 Then 'acrescenta 00 antes do cod do produto
        Produto = "00" & Produto
    End If
    If Len(Produto) = 4 Then 'acrescenta 0 antes do cod do produto
        Produto = "0" & Produto
    End If

    Imagem = Dir("\\Clfssrvfar\ENGENHARIA\GESTAO_DE_PROJETOS\04. FOLLOWUP\09. ARQUIVOS PARA FERRAMENTAS\09.1 IMAGENS\09.1.2 IMAGENS PRODUTOS\" & Produto & "*", vbDirectory)

    CaminhoImagem = "\\Clfssrvfar\ENGENHARIA\GESTAO_DE_PROJETOS\04. FOLLOWUP\09. ARQUIVOS PARA FERRAMENTAS\09.1 IMAGENS\09.1.2 IMAGENS PRODUTOS\" & Imagem



    With ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(CaminhoImagem) 'Mostra Imagem
        'Define tamanho e posição da imagem

    With .ShapeRange
        .Width = 75
        .Height = 115
        .Top = 7
        .Left = 715
        '*above it's me trying to make white background transparent*
            'With .PictureFormat
            '.TransparentBackground = True
            '.TransparencyColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            'End With
        '.Fill.Visible = True
        'End With
        'ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture 2")).Select
        'Application.CommandBars("Format Object").Visible = False
    End With
    End With
    If CaminhoImagem <> "" Then 'Após inserir imagem informa "ok" na B2 para não inserir de novo
    Range("B2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "OK"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with the sub `ForEachWs()`?

Comment: I want it to be automatic I just start the macro and it goes through every sheet, otherwise i would have to acces each sheet in order to input the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to run the sub `BuscarImagemTavares` for every worksheet you have, you have to alter both the subs `ForEachWs` and `BuscarImagemTavares`.

ForEachWs:

```
Sub ForEachWs()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        'Here you can directly call the sub without the sub Worksheet_SelectionChange
        Call BuscarImagemTavares(ws, ws.Cells(1,2).Value)
        'in BuscarImagemTavares you´ll need the ws reference to actually work on the right worksheet (otherwise youll always work on the selected one)
    Next ws

End Sub
```

BuscarImagemTavares:

```
Sub BuscarImagemTavares(ByVal ws as Worrksheet, Produto As String)
    'Mind the additional parameter 'ws'
    On Error Resume Next
    'Autor: Tavares

    'If Range("B2") = "ok" Then 'Verifica se celula B2 tem ok se sim não insere a imagem novamente
    If ws.Range("B2") = "ok" Then 'Here you actually have to use a reference to the Worksheet you want to use, otherwise alwys the same will be used
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ...

    'You need the reference here as well so you won#t use the same worksheet over and over again
    With ws.Pictures.Insert(CaminhoImagem) 'Mostra Imagem

    ...

    If CaminhoImagem <> "" Then 'Após inserir imagem informa "ok" na B2 para não inserir de novo
        'Range("B2").Select
        'ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "OK"
        'If you don´t actually need the cell in excel to be selected after the programm finished you should´nt use the '.select' and '.selection' instead use this:
        ws.Range("B2").Value= "OK" 'Since you aren´t adding a formula you should address the '.value' property
    End If

    ...

End Sub
```

Hope I could help you a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the Event-Routine `Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange`. This is a routine that is called from Excel automatically when the user is changing the selected cell (moving cursor). It is allowed to call the event-routine by hand, but you have to pass a `range` as parameter (representing the range that was selected), for example:

```
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    Call Worksheet_SelectionChange(ws.cells(1,2))
Next ws
```

This will satisfy the compiler, however, why not calling the real routine directly:

```
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    Call BuscarImagemTavares (ws.cells(1,2).value)
Next ws
```

Comment: Yep it worked, So cool, the problem now is that it is inputing all the pictures in 1 sheet instead of 1 picture in each sheet.

Comment: This is because you work on the activeSheet-object. Either insert a ws.activate in front of the call (bad) or pass the whole worksheet as parameter and work on that. I just started to change the code, but FatTony was faster...